# preventing vim from adding a file to the oldfiles list

Tags: vim

I use aliases with vim to edit large collections of files. This looks something like:

```
whole_lotta_vim *.c
```

However, this alias fills up vim's oldfiles list with a bunch of useless crud. Is there a way to prevent vim from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting Vim with `-i NONE` disables the use of the `:help viminfo-file`. This means that Vim won't store marks for any of the file you open, which is what you want, but it also means that it won't be able to access anything stored in the `viminfo` file, like command history and so on, which may be a compromise you are not willing to make.